# Different duration of call to GetDiskFreeSpaceEx

Tags: c, windows, winapi

In my programme I call periodically [`GetDiskFreeSpaceEx()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364937.aspx). It seems strange
that the call takes different time from 10 - 15 milliseconds to
8 - 15 seconds. I'm running it on Windows 7 and Windows 7 Embedded.
Can somebody explain why the time difference is so big?

Comment: I have observed the same thing at times. Don't know why it can take so long.

Comment: Sounds like the system caches the information and periodically decides to refresh it.

Comment: The long response times could be when Windows needs to fetch data from the disk to calculate the result, and the disk been idle and spun down.